# How to adjust Banner Ad in ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I saw one app if internet is OFF list touch bottom and if internet is ON .....Banner ad appears and list goes exact above banner ad....How to do this??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout`, place the ad below and the `ScrollView` above it, so just set it programmatically when you have internet define `setVisibility(VISIBLE);` and when you don't have `setVisibility(GONE);`and `ScrollView` will fill the entire screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: setVisibility(VISIBLE) and banner ad overlap content....how to set margin

Comment: the ScrollView content must be above the banner, as shown in the code above, when it is visible the layout will adjust accordingly